# Snaplogic Select Multiple Columns

Tags: database, etl, snaplogic

Can I select multiple columns in Snaplogic and perform a min/max/avg on them? I've attached a picture below. I would like to select data from 1960-1963 and find the avg/min/max for the specific country.

[SnapLogic Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmC4y.png)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Way 1 :

Use the **Aggregate** snap with the math function of your choice.

Way 2 :

Use the **< platform > - Execute** snap (eg, SQL Server - Execute) to write your own query which includes these math functions. This is great if you need `CASE` statements.